# Android ListAdapter notifyDataSetChanged doesn't work when I add my custom adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, listadapter

on onCreate i use this

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = createDirectoryChooserDialog(title, m_subdirs, new DirectoryOnClickListener());
```

and this is the createDirectory

```
private AlertDialog.Builder createDirectoryChooserDialog(String title, List<String> listItems, DialogInterface.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(m_context);

    // Create custom view for AlertDialog title containing
    // current directory TextView and possible 'New folder' button.
    // Current directory TextView allows long directory path to be wrapped to multiple lines.
    LinearLayout titleLayout = new LinearLayout(m_context);
    titleLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    m_titleView = new TextView(m_context);
    m_titleView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    m_titleView.setTextAppearance(m_context, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
    // m_titleView.setTextColor(m_context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
    m_titleView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    m_titleView.setText(title);

    titleLayout.addView(m_titleView);

    dialogBuilder.setCustomTitle(titleLayout);

    m_listAdapter = createListAdapter(listItems);

    dialogBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(m_listAdapter, -1, onClickListener);
    dialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);

    return dialogBuilder;
}
```

when the user clicks on a folder i use this

```
 private void updateDirectory() {

    m_subdirs.clear();
    m_subdirs.addAll(getDirectories(m_dir));
    m_titleView.setText(m_dir);

    m_listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

when the create list adapter is like this it doesnt work

```
  private MenuListAdapter createListAdapter(List<String> items) {
    int[] icons = new int[items.size()];
    String[] folders = new String[items.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        icons[i] = R.drawable.ic_folder;
        folders[i] = items.get(i);
    }
    return new MenuListAdapter(m_context, folders, icons);
}
```

but when i use it like this it works fine, I just dont have the folder image

```
        private MenuListAdapter createListAdapter(List<String> items) {

    return new ArrayAdapter<String>(m_context, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, android.R.id.text1, items) {

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            if (v instanceof TextView) {
                // Enable list item (directory) text wrapping
                TextView tv = (TextView) v;
                tv.getLayoutParams().height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                tv.setEllipsize(null);
            }
            return v;
        }
    };
```

and this is my menulistadapter

```
 public class MenuListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

// Declare Variables
Context context;
String[] mTitle;
int[] mIcon;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public MenuListAdapter(Context context, String[] title, int[] icon) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mTitle = title;
    this.mIcon = icon;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mTitle.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mTitle[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Declare Variables
    TextView txtTitle;
    ImageView imgIcon;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, parent, false);

    // Locate the TextViews in drawer_list_item.xml
    txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);

    // Locate the ImageView in drawer_list_item.xml
    imgIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

    // Set the results into TextViews
    txtTitle.setText(mTitle[position]);

    // Set the results into ImageView
    imgIcon.setImageResource(mIcon[position]);

    return itemView;
}
```

}
can anyone tell me whats the difference? what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The data set you submitted to your custom adapter is different from the one you are modifying inside  `updateDirectory()`. The way you wrote it, the simplest thing that you can do is to modify update directory this way:

```
private void updateDirectory() {
   m_subdirs.clear();
   m_subdirs.addAll(getDirectories(m_dir));
   m_titleView.setText(m_dir);
   dialogBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(createListAdapter(m_subdirs), -1, onClickListener);

}
```

Comment: they do not seem the same to me. Take a closer look

Comment: But how can i set it when the m_listAdapter is inside the dialogbuilder?

Comment: keep the dialogbuilder as memeber class and call setSingleChoiceItem with the new adapter.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not modifying the data stored in your MenuAdapter. To fix the problem you can create an *update* method in your adapter and call it when the user click :

```
private void updateDirectory() {
    m_titleView.setText(m_dir);
    m_listAdapter.updateList(getDirectories(m_dir));
```

}

And in you MenuListAdapter, add to following method

```
public void updateList(List<String> newItems){
    mIcons = new int[newItems.size()];
    mTitle = new String[newItems.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < newItems.size(); i++) {
        mIcons[i] = R.drawable.ic_folder;
        mTitle[i] = items.get(i);
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: If I try to do it like this but without the new int and new string inside the updatelist it works it just updates the first elements of the array with the new ones. If I try with the new it doesnt work at all. I think it just loses the reference to mIcons and mTitle. Also I tried with an ArrayList and instead of new to try to clear it and add the new elements but still it doesnt work :/

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the only way I managed it to work is like this

I had in onCreate this

```
AlertDialog dirsDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
```

so inside UpdateDirectory() I put this

```
ListView list = dirsDialog.getListView();
m_listAdapter = createListAdapter(m_subdirs);
list.setAdapter(m_listAdapter);
```

I don't think that thats the best way to do this but its the only way I managed it to work.